# How to assign procedure from custom unit to event handler control on main form

Tags: delphi, eventhandler

Is it real?
For example, I have `form1` and `button1`. I can **assign** to `button1.onClick` in design time only`Button26Click`.

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)    
    procedure Button26Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

I also have unit 2 like :

```
unit ProcAndFunc;
interface
uses sysutils,forms;

procedure createArrTable(Sender: TObject);
```

Can I **assign**  `createArrTable` to `button1.onClick` in **design time**?
Thanks.

Ok. Unit1

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)  
        myButton1 : TButton; 
        procedure Button26Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;
```

Unit2

```
TForm2 = class(TForm) 
            myButton2 : TButton; 
            procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
          private
            { Private declarations }
          public
            { Public declarations }
          end;
```

Just to know how it works. What should I change in `unit2` that I can assign `ButtonClick` to `myButton1.OnClick` 
[How to make a separate unit for event methods, which IDE allows me to assign to component events at design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240403/how-to-make-a-separate-unit-for-event-methods-which-ide-allows-me-to-assign-to) It seems that I duplicate question. But that answer does not suit me. Is there the other way?

EDIT3 (08.08.2016): 
I created this TDataModule;

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,dialogs;

type
  TDataModule3 = class(TDataModule)
  procedure Click2(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DataModule3: TDataModule3;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDataModule3.Click2(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowMessage('hello world');
end;   

end.

unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, unit3;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowMessage('hello world');
end;

end.
```

And I still cant assign DataModule3.Click2 to button1.onclick in design-time. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2lUx.png)). What do I also need to do?

Comment: No, for two reasons. 1) It is not a TNotifyEvent, which is a procedure of object (it's a member of a class). 2) The Object Inspector has no idea it exists, because it's not a properly defined (and published) procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I assign `createArrTable` to `button1.onClick` in design time?

Not at design-time, no.  `createArrTable()` is not a member of a class, and thus is not accessible via an object pointer at run-time.  So it does not satisfy the signature that is normally required for an `OnClick` event handler.  The IDE will not allow you to assign it at design-time.

However, you *can* assign `createArrTable()` at run-time, with some minor tweaking.

The `OnClick` event (and most RTL/VCL events in general) is implemented using a *closure*, which consists of 2 pointers - a pointer to the procedure code itself, and a pointer to an object.

When the event is fired at runtime, the compiled code extracts the object pointer from the closure and calls the procedure with that object passed to the procedure's `Self` parameter.  It is the lack of a `Self` parameter that prevents your current `createArrTable()` implementation from being used as an `OnClick` event handler.  If you were to somehow assign it as-is, the parameter list will get corrupted at runtime.

However, if you add an *explicit* `Self` parameter to `createArrTable()`, you can avoid that issue, and skip the class object requirement:

```
procedure createArrTable(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
```

The button will still try to pass an object pointer from the closure to `Self` when calling the procedue, but now you have made space for an object pointer to be passed correctly and not corrupt other parameters.  The object pointer itself becomes irrelevant and can be set to anything you want it to be, even nil.

However, since `createArrTable()` is still not a member of a class, you cannot assign it *directly* to the `OnClick` event, but you can use a `TMethod` variable to facilitate the assignment, eg:

```
var
  M: TMethod;
begin
  M.Code := @createArrTable;
  M.Data := WhateverYouWantSelfToBe; 
  Button1.OnClick := TNotifyEvent(M);
end;
```

Now `createArrTable()` will work as expected when `OnClick` is fired at run-time.

> What should I change in `unit2` that I can assign `ButtonClick` to `myButton1.OnClick`

Nothing.  It is already a suitable event handler as-is.  All you would have to do is add `unit2` to the `uses` clause of the `interface` section in `unit1` so the IDE can see `ButtonClick()` at design-time, then you would be able to assign `Form2.ButtonClick` to `myButton1.OnClick`.  Just know that you will have to setup your project to create `Form2` *before* `Form1` at runtime, otherwise you will likely crash the code when the DFM streaming system tries to access `ButtonClick` via an invalid `Form2` object when assigning the value of `Form1.myButton.OnClick`.

To avoid having to change the creation order of the Forms, you can place the event handlers into a separate `TDataModule` instead, and then link its methods to events on your Form.  Just make sure the `TDataModule` is created at runtime *before* the Form is created:

[Access DataModule's event from another Form (delphi design-time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446578/)

Comment: Whilst you can do this you should not.

Comment: Granted, there are better ways to implement this.  I'm just stating that it is *technically possible* nonetheless.  It comes in handy sometimes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! I`ll try it on Monday

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi, again! Please look at the 1st post. I added info with tdatamodule. It doesnt work(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ever assign that procedure as an event handler since it is not a method of a class. So you could make the procedure be a method of another class and make sure that there was a global instance of that class visible to the designer.

However that would be a very poor solution in my view. It is best practice to decouple UI logic from application logic where possible. The clean solution is to simply call the procedure from an event handler. That means that your procedure is still available to other parties in its current form and does not need to be shoe-horned into looking like an event handler. You could also likely remove the `Sender` parameter which I suspect you are not using in any case.

Comment: Yeah... createArrTable was in main unit and was assigned to onClick. Today I started to isolate this and other procedures to separate unit (it`s general procedure for many controls) and stuck with this. Just wanted to decrease lines in main unit.
And I thought abount "make the procedure be a method of another class" but didn`t try it.
However, thanks for quick reply!

Comment: While @davidheffernan is right, as usual, personally I'd leave the sender there which allows for multiple buttons to call the same function/procedure and you can determine which it was. Future flexibility.

Comment: @admiral Once the code is decoupled from the UI then it should not know that information. That information should be processed at the UI level.

Comment: @admiral Further you are in control of the code. If you need to add arguments later do it later. Adding unused arguments now on the off chance you might use them later is bad practise.

Comment: @davidHeffernan I yield to your experience and knowledge and agree totally. However, my own experiences have taught me that there is a 95% chance I've forgotten something and will later optimize by reusing code and often wish I'd left a simple sender in there. You are correct though, it is sloppy coding.

Comment: @admiral Trivial to add if needed, although would still be a violation of separating UI from app logic